# I need to find the name of a movie about a portal to another world

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a trailer between the years 1999 and 2005. The plot was about maybe a couple who lives in a war-ridden city and find a portal to another world either in the attic or on top of a closet. I remember that around the portal there was lots of sand.
they could move from world to the other.
I would like to watch that movie but it seems it never made to the movies where I live.
Can anyone help find which movie was that?
thanks!

Comment: Can you recall any other details?

Comment: Where did you see the trailer?

Comment: no other major detail. just that in the war-ridden world it looked like old london. the other world was sunnyIf I´m not mistaken I watched the trailer on Itunes trailer website. back in the day quicktime allowed to save the trailers

Comment: Swap 'sand' for 'snow' and this sounds a lot like *Narnia*, which came out 2005.

Comment: I recall a movie that was on Netflix (DVD) for a while, 6 or so years ago.  I think it may have been made in France.  It had something to do with portals to other worlds, and I think the picture showed some characters in sandy desertlike surroundings.

Comment: it´s not Narnia, cos I remember it very well and the couple was mature people

Answer (score 5):

I've found a possible match, going off of LAK's comment that this was French, in the film [Peut-être](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peut-%C3%AAtre).  From Wikipedia...

> After having sex with his girlfriend Lucie in a bathroom, Arthur discovers that a ceiling panel is a time portal to the Paris in the future, although it appears more like a sun-baked desert city by that point. There he meets an old man named Ako who turns out to be Arthur's son. Ako attempts to persuade Arthur to impregnate Lucie so that he can exist in this future.

Comment: it might be it. ll look for the trailer to that one

Comment: it might be it. ll look for the trailer to that one;but then again, maybe not. the present day was more gloomy. I watched the trailer.